# small gap between two divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I am having issues to make small gap between two divs. I have tried offset but still its not working here is my code

```css
 .box1 {
    background-color:black;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0">
        <div class="box1">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">

 <div class="box1">

        </div>

    </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is if set second div col-md-offset-0 it gets too close first div and if I set to 1 or above it sets very big gap. I want very small gap

Comment: Have you tried using the `*-sm-*` (small) mods that Bootstrap provide?

Comment: Yes but isn't it for smaller screens?

Comment: Fix you HTML first, that is not valid Bootstrap code. A `row` can only be inside `container` and `col-*` can only be inside a `row`.

Comment: The BS grid system is not designed to have “small gaps” between the columns. The offset classes offset by whole column widths only. You should handle this _inside_ your column(s) - leave them as wide as they are and without gaps, and use margins on the content.

Comment: @CBroe can you give an example?

Comment: could be any height. its not necessary to have col-md-1 my purpose is to get both divs close to each other

Comment: By default, Bootstrap grid has a gutter of 30px between columns (15 px padding on each side). If that's too big you maybe better off not using the grid for this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Try adding margin with a custom class-name on the col divs.
like so

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- custom-spacer is a custom class-name. to add extra margin. -->
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0 custom-spacer">
            <div class="box1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.box1 {
    background-color:black;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.custom-spacer {
    margin-right: 40px; /* Increase or decrease the margin as required. */
}
</style>
```

There could be one problem with this approach, because you are increasing the gutter size, you will not be able to create 12 cols within the same row.

Comment: not working in fact padding is not the problem the issue is of margin.